# English translations of Kavyalankara Sangraha by Udbhata Bhatta

Tags: translation-request, nyaya

I'm looking for a english translation of Kavyalankara Sangraha by Udbhata Bhatta. From what I've heard it is a stellar book on Indian system of Logic. If no translations are available a detail summary of the contents, key concepts and review would do.

Comment: Udbhatta Bhatta was the author of two works, the Kavyalankara Vritti and the Alankara Sangraha.  The first work is lost and the second work still exists, but both of those works are about poetics, the study of poetry, not Nyaya or logic.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I'm referring to this one - https://archive.org/details/TheKavyalankaraSangrahaOfUdahaBhatta